# How to correctly unpickle a file (ModuleNotFoundError)?

Tags: python, pickle, mfcc, gmm

I saved a model using Pickle using this code below:

```
picklefile = path.split("-")[0]+".gmm"
Pickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'w'))
print '+ modeling completed for person:',picklefile," with data point = ",list_features.shape    
list_features = np.asarray(())
count = 0
```

Now I want to unpickle the file using this method:

```
models = [pickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
```

But I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'

I would expect the output to unpickle the saved file.

I also tried importing `from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as gmm` and I still get the same error. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: What is the version of scikit-learn you are using?

Comment: Can you try pickling it and unpickling it in the same script/file?

Comment: It does look like you are not writing the file in binary mode, so try changing the `'w'` to `'wb'` on the `open()` call — not sure if/why that would cause the error you're seeing, but it should be corrected.

Comment: Version of scikit-learn: 0.21.3

Comment: how did you install sklearn? if not this, try it: `sudo apt install python3-sklearn`?

Comment: Also, include both imports. `import sklearn.mixture.gmm` and `import sklearn`, try upgrading sklearn to latest version. You are also required to have `python3.5` or a newer version installed.

Comment: I am using on windows, so sudo apt will not work.

Comment: @mirana, I have tried your approach by importing both the packages, but got below error: import sklearn.mixture.gmm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'

Comment: I have installed sklearn via below command: conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn

Comment: What if you replace `Pickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'w'))` with `Pickle.dump(sklearn.mixture.gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'w'))` and only do `import sklearn`?

Comment: Still getting the same error.